# Multiple formatter date options in jqgrid

Tags: date, jqgrid, formatter

I have a date field in jqgrid that doesn't sort correctly. The reason is because I my initial `formatter:'date'` is getting overwritten by my second reference to `formatter: function(...)`. 
How do I preserve both pieces of functionality ?

Here is my code:

```
{name:'FUSInvitedDateX',hidden:true,index:'FUSInvitedDateX',width:'250',
search: true,searchoptions:{sopt:['eq','ne','lt','le','gt','ge'], dataInit: 
function(elem) {$(elem).datepicker();}},sorttype: 'date', 
formatter:'date',formatoptions: {srcformat: 'm/d/Y', newformat: 'm/d/Y' },
formatter: function(cellvalue, options, rowObject) { return 
highlight(cellvalue, options, rowObject, ['FUSScheduledDateX','FUSCompletedDateX','InterviewStatus_DerivedX'],'interview-invite-late');}}
```

and then in the highlight function I have something like this:

```
function highlight(cellvalue,options,rowObject,compare,color) {
                if (cellvalue.length==0) { return cellvalue; }
                [ evaluating code ]
                 return '<span>' + cellvalue + '</span>';
```

Any advice would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but one can't define **two** properties with the same name in one object. On the other side you included twice the `formatter` property in the column definition. It's syntax error.

Even if you would remove `formatter:'date'` and use only custom formatter (`formatter` callback function) then `sorttype: 'date'` will not work because jqGrid will be unable to parse the date correctly.

If you really need to use custom formatter (callback function) then you should define `sorttype` as callback function too. You can parse the input string inside of `sorttype` function and return it as ISO date (like 2017-06-15).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Do you have any example code on how I would modify the solution above to a) allow a filtered date field and still b) allow for a custom formatter. Much appreciated.

Comment: @richnwilson: `sorttype` can be defined as callback function, which should return the value, which should be used **instead of** original value during sorting. If you use `srcformat: 'm/d/Y'` like 06/16/2017 then you can convert it to `'Y-m-d'` like 2017-06-16. Thus the code of `sorttype` could be in simplified form the following: `sorttype: function (cellValue) { var parts = cellValue.split('/'); return parts[2] + '-' + parts[0] + '-' parts[1]; }`. Real code could be a little more complex if your source data could be 6/16/2017 instead of 06/16/2017 and the data could be empty or undefined.

Comment: Thanks. I believe I have the sort order resolved, using the following: `sorttype: function(cellValue) { if (cellValue.length==0 || typeof cellValue === "undefined" ) { return false;} else {var $parts = cellValue.split('/'); var $yyyy = $parts[2]; var $m = $parts[0].length < 2 ? '0' + $parts[0] : $parts[0]; var $d = $parts[1].length < 2 ? '0' + $parts[1] : $parts[1]; return $yyyy + "-" + $m + "-" + $d;}}` **however** the date filter does not seem to work. I have tried boolean conditions of =, <=, >= using the datepicker but it just shows blanks.

Comment: I believe I have now fixed this. I changed `dataInit: 
function(elem) {$(elem).datepicker();}}` to `dataInit: function(elem) {$(elem).datepicker({dateFormat: 'm/d/yy'});}}`. Does that sound right ?

Comment: @richnwilson: I can't help you without having **the demo**, which include some test data.

Comment: Hi Oleg. In the end I was able to modify the data to ensure all date fields were always the 10 characters i.e. 06/06/2017. Once I did that your sorttype code worked perfectly. Thanks for all your assistance. Appreciated.